# Integral with square root of function of function

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the function $y=y(x)$ with $y'=dy/dx$, and the following equation:
$ky'=\pm\sqrt{k^{2}-y^{2}}$, where $k$ is constant.

Integrating this, given that $y(0)=0$, should give: $y=k\sin(x/k)$.

I don't know how such an integration was calculated and how we arrived at this result. Any help explaining the integration process would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can we assume $k$ is a constant

Comment: Yes, $k$ is constant. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: It is basically the fact that $\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\arcsin t+C$.

Comment: but how exactly do you handle this, since the exact form of $y(x)$ (i.e. how it depends on $x$) here is not known during integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $k$ is a constant, you have
$$k*\frac{dy}{dx} = \pm\sqrt{k^2-y^2}$$
$$\frac{k*dy}{\pm\sqrt{k^2-y^2}} = dx$$
Integrating both sides we get
$$k\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{k}\right) = x +C$$
This is because
$$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}} = \arcsin(\frac{u}{a}) + C$$
For a constant $a$.

Then just solve for $y$.

Comment: You dropped a $\pm$ when you integrated... :) (But +1 anyway)